# Equivalent to git clean -xfd ; git reset --hard in Mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

My usual workflow to update my self-compiled software is

```
git clean -xfd
git reset --hard
git pull
./configure
# ...
```

**What would be the equivalent for** `clean -xfd` **and** `reset --hard` **in Mercurial?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of `git clean -xfd` is:

```
hg purge --all
```

You need to enable the purge command first by turning on the purge "extension" (extension being a bit of a misnomer, because like many other Mercurial extensions it is actually a part of core Mercurial that is disabled by default because it is potentially dangerous). Enabling purge is done by adding

```
[extensions]
purge=
```

to your `~/.hgrc` (or the `.hgrc` in your local repository copy, if you don't want to turn it on globally).

The equivalent of `git reset --hard` is:

```
hg revert --all
```

(or `-a` as a shorthand for the `--all` option). This will leave backups by default. Use the `-C/--no-backups` option to not have them or simply run `hg purge --all` after `hg revert --all` instead of the other way round.